# Bootstrap Datetimepicker missing an hour

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I need some help. I have a time picker format to 'HH::mm' (24 hours time). Using [bootstrap timepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) it's already working until today its missing the '2'(AM hour) time.

here's how i declair my time picker

```
$('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm'
    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $(this).trigger('update:timepicker');
    });
```

Do anybody have an idea what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. Just wanna post my answer if encase someone bumps onto this problem.
So the timezone i am handling right now is in USA which uses [DST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/) and according to this [list](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html) , 02:00 → 03:00 (Forward)

Im using 4.0.0 version of bootstrap datetimepicker because its already fixed on the latest version according to [their change log](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Changelog/).